# Create dynamic gridview and automatically refresh all items in html page using java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a blog website using html and javascript where I add blogs contains titles, paragraphs & pictures using the form submit button.
Here listofobject I take it as a list and depends on number of items of the list gridview automatically generate using javascript code:-

```js
import blogger from "./blogger.js";


let listOfObjects = [];



const validate =
  function valid() {


    let title = document.getElementById("title").value;



    let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1").value;



    let image = document.getElementById("myimage").value;
    // alert("Welcome to External JS file 4")

    var obj = new blogger(

      title,
      textarea,
      image

    );

    listOfObjects.push(obj);








    grid(main, listOfObjects)


  }

const form = document.getElementById('add-blog-form');
form.onsubmit = validate;

const main = document.querySelector(".maincontent");

window.onload = grid(main, listOfObjects);

function grid(main, list) {

  let container = document.createElement("div");
  container.id = "maingrid";

  container.className = "container";
  main.appendChild(container);
  let maingrid = document.getElementById('maingrid');
  let keys = Object.keys(list);
  let len = keys.length

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    // row.classList.add('row row-cols-auto');
    row.className = "row";
    row.id = "row" + i;
    maingrid.appendChild(row);
    let roww = document.getElementById('row' + i);
    for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
      let box = document.createElement("div");
      box.className = "col";
      // box.classList.add('rightcolumn');
      box.id = "col" + j;
      roww.appendChild(box);
      let h1 = document.createElement("H1");
      h1.setAttribute("style", "color:black;font-size:24px;");
      // h1.setAttribute("class", "blogheading");
      let h1id = "h1" + j;
      h1.setAttribute("id", h1id);
      let xContent = document.createTextNode(list[i].title);
      h1.appendChild(xContent);
      box.appendChild(h1);

      let p = document.createElement("P");
      p.setAttribute("style", "black:white;font-size:24px;");
      var pid = "p" + j;
      p.setAttribute("id", pid);
      let pcontent = document.createTextNode(list[i].textarea);
      p.appendChild(pcontent);
      box.appendChild(p);

      let img = document.createElement('img');
      let imgid = "img" + j;
      img.setAttribute("id", imgid);
      img.setAttribute('alt', '')
      img.setAttribute('loading', 'lazy')
      img.style.height = "300px"
      img.style.width = "300px"
      img.src = list[i].image;
      // 'https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg';
      box.appendChild(img);



    }
  }

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container1 ">
  <form class="form-group" id="add-blog-form" action="AddBloggs.html">
    <h2>Blogger Page</h2>
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="Title" id="title" class="form-control" /><br />
    <label>TextArea</label>
    <textarea name="comment" id="textarea1" placeholder="Text" class="form-control "></textarea>
    <br />
    <label>Image</label>
    <input type="text" name="myImage" id="myimage" placeholder="URL" class="form-control " />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success " />
    <input type="reset" value="reset" class="btn btn-info" />
  </form>
</div>

<main class="maincontent"></main>
```

I am unable to see any data in html page. I debugged my code and I am able to add successfully in listofobject. I hope my html code for grid generation is the correct only thing I am unable to add a class of bootstrap to my grid row and column. I have a doubt as to if I am calling grid generation function in valid() method thus why it is unable to show in html. I mean is there any scope problem.
Could you please help in this regards?
Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just use a framework like Vue, If you do, you will only write the for loop, the framework will do the element creation and appending and much much more, you dont need to do all this

Comment: Dear sir,I don't have enough knowledge about vue.js...but thank you for suggestion.

Comment: you can do this in Vuejs in the next day you start learning it, it is very simple, start with the documentation

Comment: okye thank you, let me try